# How to use a column from a Hive table to define the timezone in from_utc_timestamp function

Tags: datetime, hadoop, hive

I have a hive table, with a transaction utc_time_date -  in UTC, and timezone stored as a string

```
customerid              string
sessionid               string
utc_time_date           string
defined_cst             timestamp
variable_time           timestamp
store_nbr               int
utc_date                string
defined_cst_visit_date  string
variable_date           string
tc                      string
transactiontotal        double
usegiftcardsfirst       int
associate_flag          int
new_user                int
time_zone               string
```

`utc_time_date` was a column called session in a subquery.

When I use `FROM_UTC_TIMESTAMP(session, 'CST')`, I get the correct time/date combination.

Here is a snippet of the code that created these columns

```
session as UTC_Time_Date, FROM_UTC_TIMESTAMP(session, 'CST') as Defined_CST,
 FROM_UTC_TIMESTAMP(session, time_zone) as Variable_time,
 storeid as store_nbr, transactiondate as UTC_Date,
 to_date(FROM_UTC_TIMESTAMP(session, 'CST')) as defined_cst_visit_date,
 to_date(FROM_UTC_TIMESTAMP(session, time_zone)) as variable_date,
 tc, transactionTotal, useGiftCardsFirst, associate_flag, new_user, time_zone
```

But - `FROM_UTC_TIMESTAMP(session,timezone)` returns incorrect information as follows

```
utc_time_date   defined_cst variable_time   variable_date
11/6/2016 1:28  11/5/2016 20:28 11/6/2016 1:28  11/6/2016
```

Can one use a column as input for the timezone in this function? It's clear you can use a timestamp column as input for the date field, as that works.

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out what caused my issue - when I created the timezone table, there was extraneous white space at the end of each line. This caused the function to error, and not return the correct timezone. Lesson learned - make sue I use sed to remove white space in .csv files before using them to create tables in Hive.